# Unable to retrieve photoshop default fonts

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I installed Photoshop-CC that time it was working correctly but after installing few font's of mine and overwriting few fonts, all the text using default Photoshop font get disappeared.

Text disappeared from all the popup window and other side bars   .

Answer (score 0):

when you will open your psd file so one popup will appear on you screen.
"some text layers might need to update before the can be used for vector based output. Do you want to update these layers now?"

your just click to update. problem will solve.

if problem will not solved.

you just do below process.

Holding down the Alt + Ctrl + and Shift keys while starting up Photoshop will cause a dialog box to appear. You will be prompted to delete your Photoshop settings file.

Choosing yes will delete the settings file that Photoshop creates and updates whenever you make a change in your settings.

This will defiantly work for you.